# Problemas de redireccionamiento (www --> no-www) bajo HTTPS para sitio web construido en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ssl, dns

Para un sitio web construido con wordpress, quiero garantizar se alcance la visita del sitio web, a pesar de las distintas combinaciones que se tengan entre www, no-www, http, https.

Entiendo que google redirecciona el contenido de http a https cuando detecta la existencia de un certificado SSL.

El sitio web se encuentra alojado en un hosting y por ello a pesar de tener posibilidad de crear dominios, DNS, entre otros, no dispongo de total control sobre el servidor para realizar ajustes sobre el virtual host por mencionar algo.

A efectos de los nombre referenciales que detallo, indico:

1. Dominio: ejemplo.com (DNS A, AAAA para ejemplo.com)
2. Sub-dominio: miportal (DNS A, AAAA para miportal.ejemplo.com)
3. DNS CNAME para www.miportal.ejemplo.com vinculado con miportal.ejemplo.com
4. Certificado: SSL Starter Wildcard asociado al dominio ejemplo.com

A modo de que se aprecie lo que ocurre al momento de probar los escenarios, comparto las siguientes salidas de curl con cada uno de ellos:

**HTTP Y WWW**
Como se puede apreciar ocurre un redireccionamiento.

```
curl -v http://www.miportal.ejemplo.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.miportal.ejemplo.com/
*   Trying 126.125.124.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334: Network is unreachable
* Connected to www.miportal.ejemplo.com (126.125.124.123) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.miportal.ejemplo.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 216
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=15
< Date: Thu, 16 Apr 2020 18:33:08 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Location: https://miportal.ejemplo.com/
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://miportal.ejemplo.com/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host www.miportal.ejemplo.com left intact
```

**HTTPS Y NO-WWW**
De esta forma la pagina se muestra si problemas

```
curl -v https://miportal.ejemplo.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://miportal.ejemplo.com/
*   Trying 126.125.124.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334: Network is unreachable
* Connected to miportal.ejemplo.com (126.125.124.123) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.optimalize.es
*  start date: Apr 13 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 13 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "miportal.ejemplo.com" matched cert's "*.optimalize.es"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=Encryption Everywhere DV TLS CA - G1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x563443183ae0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: miportal.ejemplo.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< date: Fri, 17 Apr 2020 00:15:39 GMT
< server: Apache
< x-powered-by: PHP/7.3.16
< x-pingback: https://miportal.ejemplo.com/xmlrpc.php
< link: <https://miportal.ejemplo.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://miportal.ejemplo.com/>; rel=shortlink
.
. ACA SE MUESTRA TODO EL CODIGO QUE SE PROCESA DEL LADO DEL NAVEGADOR 
.
```

**HTTPS Y WWW**
De esta forma si ocurre un problema

```
curl -v https://www.miportal.ejemplo.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.miportal.ejemplo.com/
*   Trying 126.125.124.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.miportal.ejemplo.com (126.125.124.123) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.miportal.ejemplo.com:443 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.miportal.ejemplo.com:443
```

En este ultimo es que se me presenta el problema y motiva la consulta que hago.

Por ultimo comparto el contenido del .htaccess que se localiza en la raiz del directorio donde se encuentra el codigo del sitio web.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Las directivas (líneas) entre `BEGIN WordPress` y `END WordPress` se generan dinámicamente
# , y solo se deberían modificar mediante filtros de WordPress.
# Cualquier cambio en las directivas que hay entre esos marcadores se sobreescribirán.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.miportal.ejemplo\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://miportal.ejemplo.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://miportal.ejemplo.com/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Saludos.

Comment: en principio movería el segundo grupo de los rewrites al principio, la L de las reglas de wordpress frena el procesamiento ahí ( el redirect 302 found que se ve en el log pareciera ser el default de apache ), el último log de curl ( unknown protocol error ) es típico ( entre otras cosas ) de cuando apache no se hace cargo del dominio que recibe ( sería lo que sucede si nunca se reescribe en el segundo grupo )

Answer (score 0):

Tengo entendido que los enlaces tienen que empezar con http o https asi sea que tenga www,

ejemplo

```
http://www.miportal.ejemplo.com
```

y

```
https://miportal.ejemplo.com
```

Comment: Gracias Erick. Eso si lo tengo claro. La navegación web precisa alguno de esos protocolos.